# Grafana does not exist correctly name

Tags: prometheus, grafana, swarm

I'm setting up a monitoring of Swarm using Grafana and Prometheus, I followed this link:
https://dockerswarm.rocks/swarmprom/

Everything working, except the display of the names.

As you can see below. No name, node or container is displayed correctly.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckHjR.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wposu.png

Where can I configure this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you edit the panel, just below where the query of the graph is writen there's a field named `Legend` where you can write what you want.

[image: Legend field]